# Updating existing plot instead of creating new in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, histogram

I am attempting a homework problem where I am tasked to plot the histogram that results from a Galton board experiment, essentially creating normal distribution by adding one value at at a time and updating the histogram after each trial (ball). I would like to find a way to update the histogram after each addition of a new value to the distribution; instead of that my code currently makes a whole ton of plots.

So far I've set up a vector with `length=1000` (though theoretically I should be able to apply my final code to a vector of anything length?) and created a loop to add values to it using `rbinom()` with 200 "pegs" with a probability of 50% (falling left or right).

```
x<-numeric(1000) #create vector length of 1000 values of 0
for (i in 1:1000) {
  x[i]<-sum(rbinom(200,1,0.5))
  hist(x,freq=FALSE)
}
```

I have the `hist()` call within the `for loop` (this may be a cardinal sin in R...), which as you can imagine produces 1000 graphs! Definitely not the right way to go about this. Is there any way to just essentially update on top of the previous plot? I'm thinking of things like `abline()`, `lines()`, etc, which (as far as I can tell) just add lines on top of an already existing plot in R without creating a new one. This is probably because the data associated with those functions isn't the same as the data in a vector? Anyways, I haven't been able to figure this out wth google. I haven't tried using ggplot2 or the animate packages yet, though I'm only vaguely familiar with the former and I imagine there's a learning curve.

A final note: I'm fairly new to R, so I'd appreciate unrelated advice on the above code, but I also think it's very productive to work things out on your own, so I would prefer hints and/or general advice instead of pasting working code.
Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you want to see the plot developing while more and more values are generated?

Comment: If indeed (as @LAP asked) you want it animated go with `gganimate`!

Comment: Searching SO with the terms `[r] animate` got 480 hits when I did it just now. Using `[r] animate histogram` I get 12. Hence my downvote for apparent lack of effort (or at the very least documenting  search-effort.)

Comment: To @LAP and plant, yes, I want to see the plot developing as more values are generated. I will look into gg animate. Thank you for your help and I'm sorry my initial post wasn't clear enough. To 42, my apologies for not searching more before posting. I was using search terms such as update plot and for loop. Evidently these were not the correct terms to search with. I will look into threads for animate histogram. Thank you very much.